Bolted plate static and dynamic friction explanation
I will not go into the exact details of the engineering problem. Still, I kindly ask for some help with a proper explanation because I am having trouble explaining the correct principle in this situation.
Let's assume we have a steel beam of some length with a flange on both sides. Both flanges are bolted to the concrete foundation with an arbitrary number of threaded anchors to the concrete foundation. The surface in friction is steel to concrete. Let's assume that one flange plate is totaly fixed to concrete and can't slip and the other can because there is friction force produced with pretensioning the anchors.
Now, we apply a side force to one side of the beam with the flange plate that can slip. What will happen? If the friction produced by the pre-tensioned anchors is smaller than the side force, the plate slips and the beam elongates for the correct value, which depends on the value of the force and beam dimensions. Of course, there are some chaotic stick-slip things going on there, but that is too much for now.
What do I get that will happen? The beam will not elongate depending only on the force applied and its dimensions. During slippage, a dynamic friction force will counteract the force applied, and the elongation of the beam will be smaller.
How can I simply explain this to people? The whole problem is more complicated, but it boils down to being able to calculate it and not trying to present the static problem as a dynamic one like they want to do. But I have a problem explaining this. I'm looking for a simple explanation — if it is even possible from what I already did — or maybe an article that did a study of such a case. I don't know how to ask properly.
EDIT:
Here is the sketch of the problem: https://i.sstatic.net/BOcFeblz.png
I fixed the beam on one side as an ideally rigid fixing point. On the other end, the flange is bolted to the concrete floor with pre-tensioned bolts (anchors). We pull with force F, and if the force is higher than the friction, the flange will slip, and the beam will extend for the value that is corresponding with the force F. Of course, when the bolts will hit the edges of the holes, completely different things start to happen.
Now again, my debate counter side says that because the flange slips, there is kinetic friction on work and we get counter acting force that also helps to make the deformation of the beam smaller. How to corectlly or more proper, how to simply explain this?

If you have dynamic friction on an I beam you have screwed up.  And it will only slip until the bolts see a shear force.
Elongation of the beam is totally separate from your connecting system.
The beam is held in place from slipping by the tension of the bolts.  This is normally a huge number.  People tend to assume that the bolts see a shear force, but they should not. There are calculators that turn bolt torque into compression force (this is a simple machine inclined plane problem).  For example, that is what hold a car wheel in the hub, not a shear force on the studs.  So the forces holding the beam in place are fairly easily calculated.
If you get to a dynamic load then you have bolt shear, and chances are the bolts will then fail, particularly if you have a cyclic load.

I totally agree with you and I understand these principles, because I do calculations on daily basis. But when I do it, it is more of a intuitive thing of understanding. My problem here is that I got one strange explanation of a person who is not totally in this area and it is hard to explain the basics to them. I will try to post a simple sketch tomorrow for better communication here.
